# How do I consider a list of items as a single atom when threading?

Tags: associations

Suppose I have the following list of items:

```
AssociationThread[{"Jan 2021","Feb 2021","Mar 2021","Apr 2021","May 2021","Jun 2021","Jul 2021","Aug 2021","Sep 2021","Oct 2021"}->{Missing["NotAvailable"],Missing["NotAvailable"]}]
```

When I try threading, it is not considering `{Missing["NotAvailable"],Missing["NotAvailable"]}` as a single atomic object.

Is there a `Verbatim` like wrapper I can use to treat a list of items as a single atomic object during threading:

```
AssociationThread[{"Jan 2021","Feb 2021","Mar 2021","Apr 2021","May 2021","Jun 2021","Jul 2021","Aug 2021","Sep 2021","Oct 2021"}->Verbatim[{Missing["NotAvailable"],Missing["NotAvailable"]}]]
```

But it should disappear after threading is complete.

I tried using Sequence which is suppose to splice into any other head but it is not splicing into the `Rule` head.

```
AssociationThread[{"Jan 2021","Feb 2021","Mar 2021","Apr 2021","May 2021","Jun 2021","Jul 2021","Aug 2021","Sep 2021","Oct 2021"}->Sequence[{Missing["NotAvailable"],Missing["NotAvailable"]}]]
```

Desired output:

```
<|"Jan 2021" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
 "Feb 2021" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
 "Mar 2021" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
 "Apr 2021" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
 "May 2021" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
 "Jun 2021" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
 "Jul 2021" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
 "Aug 2021" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
 "Sep 2021" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
 "Oct 2021" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}|>
```

Comment: ```alist = {"Jan 2021", "Feb 2021", "Mar 2021", "Apr 2021", "May 2021", 
  "Jun 2021", "Jul 2021", "Aug 2021", "Sep 2021", "Oct 2021"}``` and ```Association[# -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], 
     Missing["NotAvailable"]} & /@ alist]``` ? Not exactly what you are looking for but a workaround perhaps.

Comment: AssociationThread[{"Jan 2021", "Feb 2021", "Mar 2021", "Apr 2021",  "May 2021", "Jun  "Oct 2021"} -> dummy[{Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}]] /. 
 dummy[x__] -> x

Answer (score 4):

```
keys = {"Jan 2021", "Feb 2021", "Mar 2021", "Apr 2021", "May 2021", 
   "Jun 2021", "Jul 2021", "Aug 2021", "Sep 2021", "Oct 2021"};


AssociationThread[keys, Defer @ {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}](*or*)

AssociationThread[keys -> Defer @ {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}]
```

[image]

You can replace `Defer` with `HoldForm` to get the same result.

You can also use [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) and specify *what* to thread over using the second and third arguments and wrap the result with `Association`:

```
Association @ Thread[keys -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}, List, 1]
```

> same result

Additional, more convoluted, ways to get the same result:

```
{#, #} & /@ AssociationThread[keys, Missing["NotAvailable"]]

ReleaseHold /@ AssociationThread[keys, 
  Hold @ {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}]

First /@ AssociationThread[keys, 
  FOO @ {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}]

List @@@ AssociationThread[keys, 
  buzz[Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]]]

Evaluate /@ AssociationThread[keys, 
  Unevaluated @ Unevaluated @ {Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}]
```

Comment: How does the `Defer` help with " "...must have same length" requirement? Is there a documentation page where I can read more about it?

Comment: @Syed, although the documentation page [AssociationThread](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html) shows only two argument patterns (`AssociationThread[{key1,key2,...} -> {val1,val2,...}]` and `AssociationThread[{key1,key2,...}, {val1,val2,...}]`) the argument patterns `AssociationThread[{key1,key2,...} -> blah]` and `AssociationThread[{key1,key2,...} , blah]` (where `blah` is any non-List expression) also work. `Defer`, because it prevents evaluation of its argument, makes `AssociationThread` use this second argument pattern.